# Unable to find Keystore file

Tags: java, android

Key-store file /home/Desktop/r  not found for signing config 'config'.
I am not able to build my app, since i'm new to android, please need some assistance!

Comment: why would you have a keystore on your desktop? it should be somewhere in the resources of your application

Comment: that's the location where i had stored my project

Comment: be that as it may, you'll need to change that to a relative path, otherwise your code won't work when you try to run it from another machine. after all, there it won't be on the desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misplaced the path to the keystore.jks file. Search for the file on my computer use that path.